# Remove spaces from XML elements

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML

```
<list>
    <foo attr1="value" attr2="red"> </foo>
    <foo attr1="xx" attr2="blue"> </foo>
    <foo attr1="yy" attr2="green"> </foo>
</list>
```

which I want to become:

```
<list>
    <foo attr1="value" attr2="red"/>
    <foo attr1="xx" attr2="blue"/>
    <foo attr1="yy" attr2="green"/>
</list>
```

Is there a XSLT option for removing the spaces out of the foo nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="foo"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <!--Identity template copies all content -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--If the foo/text() is only whitespace, don't include in output-->
    <xsl:template match="foo/text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```